# How do I use an if statement to check if a certain string of text is in another set of characters?

Tags: tcl

I want to make an if statement that will return a value when a certain characters are in another set of texts. For example if I have the words water, and fire. I want to make an if statement that will check if the word I give it has characters "wa" then it will return a value of 1. Something along the lines of this.

```
set word "water"
set tempvar 0
if {$word has characters "wa"} {
    set tempvar 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest (and fastest!) way to search for whether a substring is present is the `string first` command; that returns -1 if the substring isn't there, and the (first) index of where it is found when the substring is present.

```
if {[string first "wa" $word] >= 0} {
    set tempvar 1
}
```

The other technique that works well is one of the lesser known operating modes of Tcl's regular expression engine: if the RE starts with `***=` then the rest of the string is a literal.

```
# This is marginally slower than string first; the overhead of the RE engine matters a little
if {[regexp ***=wa $word]} {
    set tempvar 1
}
```

Note that if you were asking if it was a *prefix,* other commands are more suitable (`string equal` with the `-length` option, or `string match`). And use `lsearch` if you want to know if a particular value is an element in a list, instead of string searching.

Comment: The reason you have to be a little careful is that a lot of the more sophisticated matchers have important metacharacters. It doesn't matter when looking for `wa`, but if you're looking for `\wa` or `*wa*` it can matter a lot. A little care at the beginning makes life much easier later on.

Answer (score 1):

I would encapsulate this in a proc:

```
proc string_contains {haystack needle} { 
    expr {[string first $needle $haystack] != -1}
}
```

then

```
% string_contains water wa
1
% string_contains fire wa
0
```

and

```
% if {[string_contains water wa]} then {puts yes} else {puts no}
yes
% if {[string_contains fire wa]} then {puts yes} else {puts no}
no
```

Comment: One has to be careful about the empty string as needle then, `string first` is just broken in this respect: `string_contains water ""` will give `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in any language, for matching purpose, **Regular Expressions** are used, here used as **regexp $pattern $string** and return 1 if there is a match.

```
set word "water" 
set tempvar 0 
if {[regexp "wa" $word]} { 
    set tempvar 1 
} 
puts $tempvar
```